# Powershell Scripts To Help With Enterprise CAL Licensing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, licensing

We have an upcoming audit from Microsoft.  I'm finding it very difficult to find out which hidden features are liable for an enterprise CAL.  We have a certain number of Enterprise CALs but need to find out which web applications and site collections and webs have enterprise features enabled.

We are using SharePoint 2010.

Are there any Powershell scripts I can run to find out the features that are enabled on my Farm that require an Enterprise CAL?

Comment: which SharePoint version you are?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bedwards/archive/2011/04/23/mixing-sharepoint-standard-cals-and-enterprise-cals-on-the-same-farm.aspx there is no direct way to check which user is using as in 2013.

Comment: Are there any tools available that can run against a SharePoint 2010 Farm and return relevant information for an audit?

Answer (score 2):

Following Powershell scripts might help you:

```
PowerScript to show all web applications that have Enterprise features enabled:
 foreach ($webapp in Get-SPWebApplication) 
{ 
    foreach ($premiumfeature in Get-SPFeature "PremiumWebApplication" `
        -WebApplication $webapp.Url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
    { 
        Write-Host $webapp.Url 
    }
} 
PowerScript to show all site collections that have Enterprise features enabled:
 foreach ($site in Get-SPSite -Limit All -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{ 
    foreach ($premiumfeature in Get-SPFeature "PremiumSite" `
        -Site $site.Url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
    {
        Write-Host $site.Url
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
PowerScript to show all sub sites that have Enterprise features enabled:
 foreach ($site in Get-SPSite -Limit All -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{ 
    foreach ($web in Get-SPWeb -site $site.url -Limit ALL `
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
    { 
        foreach ($premiumfeature in Get-SPFeature "PremiumWeb" `
            -Web $web.Url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
        {
            Write-Host $web.Url, $web.Title
        }
        $web.Dispose()
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
```

From this you can get Feature name and ID.

Comment: Thanks. I had already found these scripts.  They give a list of web applications, site collections and webs that have enterprise features turned on.  When I ran them in our environment they showed that everything has premium features turned on but some of these are hidden features that we never turned on ourselves or have never used.